# EXT JS Open form on btn Click

Tags: extjs

Relativly new to EXTJS, 
I have an edit form that I want to show when the user clicks the edit button.

previously I had been doing it like this:

```
edit_window_xtype: 'window name',
```

which works perfectly, in this case I have a need to only call the form when the button is clicked and not when the user double clicks a field in my grid.(this is what edit_window_xtype: 'window name' would accomplish)

I had

```
btnEdit_onClick: function (btn) {
    Ext.create('window name').show();
},
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: can you include more code? it would be easier if you include the code for the 'window name' view and the view that the button is in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears I have alot to learn with Extjs.  Here is what I came up with, If someone has a better solution please let me know.  Always looking for better ways to accomplish something.  :)

```
btnEdit_onClick: function (btn) {
    var config = {
        xtype: 'MyWindow_Name',
        mode: 'edit',
        title: 'Edit Window',
        editId: this.id
    };
    var win = Ext.ComponentMgr.create(config);
    win.show();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

When iam doing this i'm declaring my own xtype like so:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.dialog.MyEditDialog', {
    'extend' : 'Ext.window.Window',
    'alias' : 'widget.MyEditDialog',
    'autoShow' : true,//dont have to call .show()
    'title' : 'Edit',
    'items' : [{
         'xtype' : 'form',
         'bodyPadding' : 5,//my "Default"
         'flex' : 1,//scale childs to fit parent
         'defaultType' : 'textfield',//we're lazy ;-)
         'items' : [{
             'name' : 'surename',
             'fieldLabel' : 'Surename'  
          }, {
             'name' : 'lastname',
             'fieldLabel' : 'Lastname'
          }]
     }],
     'buttons' : [{
         'text' : 'Save',
         'iconCls' : 'button-save'//declared CSS Background somewhere
     }, {
         'text' : 'Cancel',
         'iconCls' : 'button-cancel',
         'handler' : function(btn){
              btn.up('window').close();//query selector is your friend ;-)
         }
     }]
});
```

finally, saying: Ext.widget('MyEditDialog');' is enough.
Have fun!